# TSQL - How to optimize the query?

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, t-sql

I have the table with News

```
News
-------
NewsId
NewsText
CREATED_DATE
```

I need to get news starting from a specified date to a unknown date, but result should contain news for 5 days.

For example:

- if I have news related to these dates: 29th, 28th, 27th, 5th, 4th, 3rd
  and the starting date specified to 29th, I need to get news where created date between 29 and 4.

I don't know how to get the low date (4th) in that case without brute force:

```
declare @highDate date = '2011-09-20';
declare @rows int = 0;
declare @lowDate date = @highDate;
declare @i int = 0;

--Querying while rows count != 5
WHILE (@rows != 5)
BEGIN

    if (@i = 60) 
        break;

    set @i = @i + 1;
    set @lowDate = (select DATEADD(day, -1, @lowDate));

    set @rows = (select COUNT(*) from
        (SELECT DAY(CAST(CREATED_DATE AS date)) as c1
        FROM .[dbo].[NEWS]
        and CREATED_DATE > @lowDate
        and CREATED_DATE < @highDate
        group by DAY(CAST(CREATED_DATE AS date))) as rowsCount);
END

--then return news between to known dates
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[NEWS]
and CREATED_DATE > @lowDate
and CREATED_DATE < @highDate
order by CREATED_DATE desc
```

I guess in that algorithm there are too much queries against a DB and I'd like to get rid of 60-days old limitation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @highDate date = '2011-09-20'

select * from (
    select *,
           dense_rank() over (order by cast(created_date as date) desc) rnk 
    from News
    where CREATED_DATE <= @highDate
) as t
where t.rnk <= 5
```

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you.

```
declare @HighDate date = '2011-11-29'
declare @LowDate date

select @LowDate = min(N3.created_date)
from (
      select top(5) N2.created_date
      from (
            select distinct cast(N1.created_date as date) as created_date
            from news as N1
            where cast(N1.created_date as date) <= @HighDate
           ) as N2
      order by 1 desc
     ) as N3
```

Or you can use [dense_rank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

```
select @LowDate = N.created_date
from (
      select created_date,
             dense_rank() over(order by cast(created_date as date) desc) as rn
      from News 
      where cast(created_date as date) <= @HighDate 
     ) as N
where N.rn = 5
```